# Can I add an image as a logo of a GitHub repository?

Tags: github, images

I'm posting a link to a GitHub repo on Google+ and then it's giving me the GitHub logo. I would like to add logos to my GitHub repositories. Is that possible?

If that's not directly possible I will revert to adding an image to `README.md`, although that would be more tedious, since it also requires adding the image to the repository. Maybe there's a quicker alternative as well?

Not related to the main question but it is possible to add a logo to an account (including organization accounts) through gravatar.com.

Answer (score 10):

Now it's possible under the repository settings.

https://github.blog/2019-04-17-custom-open-graph-images-for-repositories/

[image]

Answer (score 9):

When posting to Twitter, Google+ or Facebook, the only logo that will come through is the image attached to the owner or organisation that owns the repository.

As such, to edit what that logo is, you will have to update the linked Gravatar image attached to the email on that owner or organisation account.

You could add an image to the repo itself, but that will often not come through as an option for the thumbnail/image that's shown with the link. Doesn't matter if the image is part of the repository, or hosted elsewhere, it won't show up.

Comment: You can add LinkedIn to the list... :(

Answer (score 8):

You cannot add an image as a logo of a GitHub repository, but `README.md` does not require adding the image to the repository as you can use external images as well, e.g.:

`![Logo](http://francky.me/images/quora001.png)`

Comment: Is that a typo in front of the exclamation mark? Also, where would one post a feature request regarding custom logos for repos, [Hub](https://github.com/github/hub/issues), [Octokit](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get), ...?